# jquery show a confirm alert before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
jQuery('#survey').on('click', function(){
    var postData = jQuery('#surveyForm').serialize();

    jQuery.post('survey.php', postData, function(data){
        alert(data);
     if($.trim(data) == "Your Score sent Successfully!") {
            location.reload();  
        }

    });     
});
```

});

this is my jquery code, can any one please help me how to add a confirm alert "are u sure you want to submit" in the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has someone stolen your `$`? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript `confirm` box as shown :-

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
   jQuery('#survey').on('click', function(){
     if(confirm("Do You want to save?")){
       var postData = jQuery('#surveyForm').serialize();

       jQuery.post('survey.php', postData, function(data){
         alert(data);
         if($.trim(data) == "Your Score sent Successfully!") {
            location.reload();  
         }
       });   
     }  
   });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9ddsp42s/)

Comment: @karthikeya:thanks its working. but the confirm box is coming before validation. what we have to do if we want it after the validation completed.

Comment: @user2989676..well you have not posted your validation code in the question...but if you want to display confirm box after validation..then in that case just use if condition having confirm  box after validation code part.

Comment: actually i didn't written any validation code.  i am simply using PHP isset command in my code to get alert boxes if the data is empty.

Comment: @user2989676..okk in that case write this code after form is valid and ready to submit...`$('#formid').on('submit',function(){....})`

Answer (score 0):

i think in your code response is not come from php file check it.
and try this  add your code in between confirm condition

```html
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
            jQuery('#survey').on('click', function(){
               if(confirm("Do You want to save?")){
//                var postData = jQuery('#surveyForm').serialize();
//
//                jQuery.post('survey.php', postData, function(data){
//                    alert(data);
//                 if($.trim(data) == "Your Score sent Successfully!") {
                        location.reload();  
//                    }

//                 });   
               }  
            });
            });
```